# Can I use OR in a CASE statement?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is there a way to use OR in a Case statement? In this example, if phoneType is one of *several values*, I want to call a function. Do I need to list every possible value with a separate WHEN statement?

````
    ```CASE ttPhoneData.phoneDescription:
            WHEN "Cell" OR "PASTORS PHONE" OR "Alternative" THEN
                RUN CreatePhone("Mobile", TRUE, ttPhoneData.phone).
            WHEN "Business" OR "ChurchPhone" OR "ChurchPhone2" THEN
                RUN CreatePhone("Work",TRUE,ttPhoneData.phone).
            WHEN "Home" THEN 
                RUN CreatePhone("Home",TRUE,ttPhoneData,phome).
        END CASE.```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you were very close. See doc at https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-122/page/CASE-statement.html?labelkey=product_openedge_122

```
CASE ttPhoneData.phoneDescription:
  WHEN 'cell' OR
  WHEN 'alternative' THEN
      . // do something
  WHEN 'business' OR
  WHEN 'churchphone' THEN
     . // somethingg else
  WHEN 'home'  THEN
     . //another thing
END CASE.
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is kind of wordy and you do need a WHEN for every value:

```
define variable test as character no-undo.

do while true:

  update test.

  case test:
    when "a" or when "b" then
      message "a or b".
    when "c" then
      message "c".
    when "d" or when "e" then
      message "d or e".
    when "z" then
      leave.
    otherwise
      message "something else".
  end.

end.
```

If you want something less wordy try this:

```
define variable test as character no-undo.

do while true:

  update test.

  if lookup( test, "a,b" ) > 0 then
      message "a or b".
   else if lookup( test, "c" ) > 0 then
      message "c".
   else if lookup( test, "d,e" ) > 0 then
      message "d or e".
   else if lookup( test, "z" ) > 0 then
      leave.
   else
      message "something else".

end.
```

or

```
define variable test as character no-undo.

do while true:

  update test.

  if ( test = "a" or test ="b" ) then
      message "a or b".
   else if ( test = "c" ) then
      message "c".
   else if ( test = "d" or test = "e" ) then
      message "d or e".
   else if ( test = "z" ) then
      leave.
   else
      message "something else".

end.
```

Comment: interesting, so you can use UPDATE  to not actually update "test", where "test" would be the phone description. clever, thx!